# Disable / Turn off FxCop CA1303 when calling LoggerExtensions methods in ASP .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, fxcop, asp.net-core-3.1

I want my logs to be in English and therefore do not want to localize them.

I have a project in ASP .NET Core 3.1 where I added the nuget package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` version 3.0.0 and I am getting the warning CA1303 on all calls to `_logger.LogInformation("")`.

I have tried to use `use_naming_heuristic` and `excluded_type_names_with_derived_types`, but they don't seem to be working with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogginExtensions` or `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`, so I always get the warnings.

This is my .editorconfig file:

```
[*.cs]

# CA1303: Do not pass literals as localized parameters
dotnet_code_quality.CA1303.use_naming_heuristic = false
dotnet_code_quality.CA1303.excluded_type_names_with_derived_types = ClassA|LoggerExtensions|ILogger
```

I have a class `ClassA` that gets an `ILogger<ClassA>` injected:

```
internal class ClassA : IClassA
{
    private readonly ILogger<ClassA> _logger;

    public ClassA(ILogger<ClassA> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Initializing..."); // <- Always get the CA1303 in this string.
    }
}
```

I tried with `true`/`false`, I tried also adding `ILogger<>` , `ILogger<T>` and `ILogger<ClassA>` but nothing makes the warning go away.

Am I misunderstanding this functionality and configuring this rule wrong or is there possible bug here?

Edit:

I added a custom class called `MyLogger` inheriting from `IMyLogger` that gets an `ILogger` injected. I injected the `IMyLogger` into the ClassA class and replace the types in `excluded_type_names_with_derived_types` with `IMyLogger` and `MyLogger` and the CA1303 is still there. I rebuilt and even restarted VS2019 16.5.4 but it is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug already fixed in version [3.3.0-beta1.20261.6](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/roslyn-analyzers/package/nuget/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/3.3.0-beta1.20261.6).

Source: [MVC Core LogCritical etc. messages should not trigger CA1303 #3254](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3254)

Comment: I am not allowed to use the beta. what alternative solution could there be?